# GNUPLOT warning : line 21: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot and I was trying to plot a graph using a script however I am getting a warning when running the script and the output .png file is not showing anything.

```
Warning is : line 21: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

The script I am using is:

```
#set title "Max Gain Approach"
frontier = "#99ffff"; hybrid = "#4671d5"
set ylabel "a" font "Times,18"
set xlabel "b" font "Times,18" offset 0,1
set auto x
set grid
set yrange [0:0.8]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9
set xtic scale 0
set output "123.png"

set key spacing 2 font "Times,18"

set xtics font "Times,16"
set ytics font "Times,16"

# 2, 3, 4, 5 are the indexes of the columns; 'fc' stands for 'fillcolor'
plot 'cqmr1.dat' using 2:xtic(1) ti col fc rgb frontier, '' u 3 ti col fc rgb hybrid

pause 10
```

And the data file `cqmr1.dat` is:

```
Title "Max Gain Approach" Frontier

"10"    0.7902
"15"    0.6834
"20"    0.6589
"25"    0.6123
"30"    0.5678
```

Answer (score 0):

The output file doesn't contain anything, because you must explicitely close it when you are in interactive mode. Put a

```
set output
```

(yes, without any parameters) after the plot command.

Then you see one set of boxes. The warning comes from your second plot part (`'' u 3  ...`). Your plot file doesn't have a third column, and so there is no data to be plotted.